# Javascript gets undefined on array

Tags: javascript

I have the following data structure for javascript:

```
var data =  {
    "announcements": {
        "IFT4S": [{
            "id": "D7214",
            "read_state": "unread",
            "posted_at": "2018-10-25T14:35:54Z",
            "title": "Reminder! Systems disruption: 27-28 Oct",
            "message": "All University online systems will be unavailable."
        }, {
            "id": "B399C",
            "read_state": "read",
            "posted_at": "2018-10-22T09:04:48Z",
            "title": "Stem Fair",
            "message": "The STEM Careers Fair is taking place on 31 October 2018"
        }, {
            "id": "6F5EE",
            "read_state": "unread",
            "posted_at": "2018-10-22T09:04:48Z",
            "title": "Smile more, worry less with our FREE course",
            "message": "Take part in our Online Mindfulness Programme."
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to access the values of the keys "read_state", "posted_at", "title" and "message".
However, when I try `data.announcements.IFT4S["title"]` or any other key instead of "title" I get the *undefined* in the console.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `IFT4S` is an array. You will need to iterate over it to access objects. e.g. `data.announcements.IFT4S[0]["title"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IFT4S is an array, you can access its objects and their values values by calling:

```
data.announcements.IFT4S[index].title
```

with index beeing one of 0-2 here since the array contains 3 objects.
For example:

```
data.announcements.IFT4S[0].title
```

This is a very basic concept, check out any javascript guide to learn about arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You have to itrate over the array to get value from an array of object

```js
var data = {
  "announcements": {
    "IFT4S": [
    {
        "id": "D7214",
        "read_state": "unread",
        "posted_at": "2018-10-25T14:35:54Z",
        "title": "Reminder! Systems disruption: 27-28 Oct",
        "message": "All University online systems will be unavailable."
      },
      {
        "id": "B399C",
        "read_state": "read",
        "posted_at": "2018-10-22T09:04:48Z",
        "title": "Stem Fair",
        "message": "The STEM Careers Fair is taking place on 31 October 2018"
      },
      {
        "id": "6F5EE",
        "read_state": "unread",
        "posted_at": "2018-10-22T09:04:48Z",
        "title": "Smile more, worry less with our FREE course",
        "message": "Take part in our Online Mindfulness Programme."
      },
    ]
  }
}

data.announcements.IFT4S.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.title)
})
```

or you can do like this,
`0` is the index

```js
    console.log(data.announcements.IFT4S[0].read_state)
    console.log(data.announcements.IFT4S[0].title)
```

Comment: Nice. Might I suggest using item.title in your working example. The secondary example is not connected properly so it's broken. Still really good.

Answer (score 1):

> when I try data.announcements.IFT4S["title"] or any other key instead
>   of "title" I get the undefined in the console. What am I doing wrong?

What you are doing here is trying to access the *title* key of the IFT4S array.

The issue is that IFT4S doesn't have a *title* key. Instead, like an array object, it has indexes as keys.

```
IFT4S = [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
```

To access the first element of the IFT4S array you would do it like this

```
IFT4S[0]
```

In your case that would return the object at the first position of IFT4S array (*index 0*)

```
{
    id: "D7214",
    read_state: "unread",
    posted_at: "2018-10-25T14:35:54Z",
    title: "Reminder! Systems disruption: 27-28 Oct",
    message: "All University online systems will be unavailable."
}
```

If you want to get all the titles from all the elements inside IFT4S array you could do this

```
IFT4S.map(element => element.title)
```

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array where each element is the result of applying the function specified inside map to each element of the original array.

In this case, it would return

```
[
    "Reminder! Systems disruption: 27-28 Oct",
    "Stem Fair",
    "Smile more, worry less with our FREE course"
]
```